# Why can I modify a string defined using defparameter?

Tags: common-lisp

I tried this in SBCL 2.0.1:

```lisp
(let ((s "Tom's house"))
  (setf (subseq s 0 5) "Cat")
  s)
```

I got a warning:

```
; in: LET ((S "Tom's house"))
;     (SETF (SUBSEQ S 0 5) "Cat")
; --> LET* 
; ==>
;   (REPLACE #:SEQUENCE #:NEW1 :START1 0 :END1 5)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   Destructive function REPLACE called on constant data: "Tom's house"
;   See also:
;     The ANSI Standard, Special Operator QUOTE
;     The ANSI Standard, Section 3.2.2.3
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
```

But when I tried the code below, I get no warnings or errors. Why can I modify a string defined using `defparameter` (or `defvar`) but not a string defined using `let`?

```lisp
(defparameter *s* "Tom's house")
(setf (subseq *s* 0 3) "Cat")
```

Comment: one might expect such a warning when compiling a file. Doesn't look like there is a specific reason for not warning, other than that it simply is missing this feature.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Is string modification completely disallowed in Common Lisp?

Comment: It's not disallowed. You can modify strings created at runtime. But for literal strings (those embedded in source code) the effects of modifying them is undefined in portable Common Lisp. For example if you have two DEFPARAMETER forms with strings having the same contents, then the compiler might optimize the space and allocate only one string -> reusing this string for both variables. Then modifying one string would see effects in two different variables. Another effect could be that a compiler allocates code (and thus the data for it) in read-only memory.

Comment: This read-only memory allocation is unsual, but on some newer systems this may actually be more common: Apple's iOS on ARM may not allow code modification (that's also why a Common Lisp compiler on iOS is not allowed to create/load code at runtime) and the latest macOS has a similar feature.

Comment: I don't understand the reference to Section 3.2.2.3. [link] (http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/03_bbc.htm) It makes reference to constant variables, not constant data. It looks like a sensible and worthwhile warning, though.

Comment: "The consequences are undefined if literal objects (including quoted objects) are destructively modified" in the definition of quote is more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments: you are not allowed to modify literal objects, and specifically, from [the definition of `quote`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_quote.htm)

> The consequences are undefined if literal objects (including quoted objects) are destructively modified.

What that means is 'don't do this in conforming programs'.  What it *does not mean* is 'the system is required to prevent you from doing this'.

In particular it should be clear that a system which *did* prevent you doing this would have either to allocate all literals in some special area of memory so that memory protection can deal with the problem, or have a whole series of secret paired mutable/immutable types for objects which can be literals (or perhaps a 'mutable' bit in the tags of objects).  The latter is what, I think, languages like Racket do: they have mutable and immutable strings, for instance.

Requiring the implementation to check this is requiring strategies which may be very hard, and some of which may not even always be possible (for instance the special-memory-area trick assumes that the architecture supports read-only bits on memory pages, which is not something the language should assume).  So the language spec just says 'the consequences are undefined'.

However, quite clearly, there are cases where a smart compiler can detect some obviously bogus code.  One is this:

```
(let ((x "literal string"))
  ... do not assign to x ...
  (setf (char x 0) ...)
  ...)
```

A smart compiler (particularly one that is doing fancy type inference) can easily see that the value of `x` you are mutating is a literal string and can warn you about that at compile time and/or raise an exception at run-time.

Compare that with your second example:

```
(defparameter *x* "a literal string")
...
(setf (char *x* 0) ...)
```

In order to deal with this, the compiler would have to prove that `*x*` actually *was still a literal string* at the point where you tried to mutate its value.  Doing that requires some kind of whole-program analysis: it needs to know everything that happened in between the definition of `*x*` and the assignment.  And while that is, perhaps, sometimes possible – for instance, the code is in a file being compiled you *are* using `defparameter` (because `defvar` won't work!) and there is nothing between the definition and the mutation – it certainly is not always possible.

So what you are seeing is that the SBCL compiler is successfully detecting some cases, but not all.  And that's fine: that's better than not detecting any.

Comment: "because `defvar` won't work!" — Why wouldn't `defvar` work?

Comment: @Flux: because immediately after `(defvar *x* "foo")` all the compiler can know about `*x*` is that it is bound: it can't know anything at all about the type of the thing it's bound to.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried running the above code in the REPL of SBCL. I confirm the above observations.

The real underlying problem comes from `replace`, as the error message suggests.

```
; doesn't work
(let ((s "Tom's house"))
  (setf (subseq s 0 5) "Cat")
   s)

; does work
(defparameter *s* "Tom's house")
(setf (subseq *s* 0 3) "Cat")

; also works
(replace "Tom's house" "Cat")
```

So:

1. We can change literal strings without complaint or warning
2. The problem appears to come from `let`

Exploring some more:

```
(defun myfunc ()
   (let ((s "Tom's house"))
      s))
```

The disassembly is `(disassemble 'myfunc)`:

```
; disassembly for MYFUNC
; Size: 30 bytes. Origin: #x1003CA1DD3               ;MYFUNC
; D3:       498B4510         MOV RAX, [R13+16]               
; D7:       488945F8         MOV [RBP-8], RAX
; DB:       840425F8FF1020   TEST AL, [#x2010FFF8]   ; 
; E2:       488B15B7FFFFFF   MOV RDX, [RIP-73]       ; "Tom's house"
; E9:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; EC:       F8               CLC
; ED:       5D               POP RBP
; EE:       C3               RET
; EF:       CC10             INT3 16    ; Invalid argument count trap
NIL
```

The string literal appears to be held on the heap, and pointed to, rather than being on the stack.

I guess that `let` doesn't like its values being changed like that.

Comment: a warning is not an error